# Alter value of field before loading

Tags: entities

I'm just wondering if its possible to alter a field before loading.

Here is the situation.

Im using commerce kickstart.

When I'm in a product page(inner page or product details page), I want to change the value of **field_my_field** before it load up to the page.

In pseudocode:
If **field_my_field** == "something" change **field_my_field** to "my custom value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy! where do you want to display the field?

If it is a view, then you can use `template_preprocess_views_view` if it is a node, you can use `hook_preprocess_node` function to alter the values. where your content is going to be displayed?